# Node.js Child process can not catch windows exe file's output

Tags: node.js, windows, outputstream, child-process, spawn

I want to use `child_process.spawn` to execute a windows exe file and catch it's output.

When I use command line to run a thirdparty exe file (says `A.exe`), it will print some logs to the cmd window. Like this:

```
C:\> A.exe
some outputs...
some more outputs...
```

However, when I spawn it in node.js, using this

```
import childProcess from 'child_process';

const cp = childProcess.spawn('A.exe');
cp.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(`stdout: ${data}`));
cp.stderr.on('data', data => console.log(`stderr: ${data}`));
```

There is no outputs at all.

I think the outputs of `A.exe` is not to the stdout (so I can never get data by listening stdout), but I don't know how it print logs when running from command line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

On Unix-type operating systems (Unix, Linux, macOS) `child_process.execFile()` can be more efficient because it does not spawn a shell. On Windows, however, .bat and .cmd files are not executable on their own without a terminal, and therefore cannot be launched using `child_process.execFile()`. When running on Windows, .bat and .cmd files can be invoked using child_process.spawn() with the shell option set, with `child_process.exec()`, or by spawning cmd.exe and passing the .bat or .cmd file as an argument (which is what the shell option and child_process.exec() do). In any case, if the script filename contains spaces it needs to be quoted.

```
// On Windows Only ...
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const bat = spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'my.bat']);

bat.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

bat.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

bat.on('exit', (code) => {
  console.log(`Child exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to execute an .exe file instead of a .bat file. Even when I use `spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'A.exe'])`, there is no output at all...

Comment: Please check following link, I have shared you screencast [link](https://www.screencast.com/t/rQRLYMukFBv)

Comment: I've watched it, thanks. The question is I can't get outputs even by using `spawn('cmd.exe', ['/c', 'A.exe'])`. So I'm wondering if the outputs of `A.exe` is not to stdout. But I still can not figure out why it print logs when running from command line.

Comment: This answer doesn't appear to address the original question on `spawn` which is an entirely different `child_process` capability. The example code is just copied from nodejs.org without attribution and the majority of the text is also copied from nodejs.org without attribution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give this approach a go:

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');
childProcess.exec('A.exe', function(error, stdout, stderr) {

    if (error != null) {
        console.log('error occurred: ' + error);
    } else {
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    }
});

// OR
var cp = childProcess.spawn('A.exe');

cp.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data.toString());
});

cp.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data.toString());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but `toString()` does not fix this issue...There is still no output at all.